# Deletion control button on UITableview edit mode is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, editmode

I have implemented `UITableview` edit mode when a button is clicked but every time it goes to edit mode and I click on the deletion button, nothing happens. I have a view controller with a `UITableview` on it. I have set my delegate and tableview source as well as all of my editing callbacks. Everything is working (like reordering cells) but whenever I try to delete by pressing the delete control button, the delete button doesn't show up.

I am desperate since it seems like a really simple problem but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work.

This is how I am implementing edit mode

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:

(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [favoriteCurrencyValueList removeObjectForKey:[favoriteCurrencyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [favoriteCurrencyList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSUserDefaults *defaultSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultSettings setObject:favoriteCurrencyList forKey:@"FavoriteCurrencies"];
    [defaultSettings setObject:favoriteCurrencyValueList forKey:@"PastValues"];
    [defaultSettings synchronize];
    [self.favoriteCurrencyTable beginUpdates];
    [self.favoriteCurrencyTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.favoriteCurrencyTable endUpdates];
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    indexPathSelected = indexPath;
    //[self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    [self.favoriteCurrencyList exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.favoriteCurrencyList forKey:@"FavoriteCurrencies"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

This is what sets the edit mode

```
- (IBAction)editButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (self.editing && self.favoriteCurrencyTable.editing) {
        self.editing = NO;
        [self.favoriteCurrencyTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.editButton setTitle:@"Edit"];
    }
    else {
        self.editing = YES;
        [self.favoriteCurrencyTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.editButton setTitle:@"Done"];
    }
}
```

Comment: send the delete code

Comment: There you go :) @RameshMuthe

Comment: your code is fine.And are you using any gestures in this controller?

Comment: Just a tap gesture recognizer on the view controller to dismiss the keyboard @RameshMuthe

Comment: For some time remove the tap gesture and see, does it works or not ?

Comment: It actually does!! Why is that? @RameshMuthe

Comment: I will post the solution how to solve this.

Comment: send the code of adding tap gestures also

Comment: - (IBAction)screenTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}        This is atached to the view of the viewController

Comment: adding tap gestures I asked.

Comment: you got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && touch.view.tag==<Button_TAG>)) {
        // prevent recognizing touches on the slider
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

For tap gestures add the delegate and write the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: I did implement that method and that is why the swipe to delete works. But since I am not inserting any rows on edit mode, what difference does it make to differentiate between the editing styles?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know this since you did not post your code originally. Of course, if you do not want to insert cells, there is no need for the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If delete does not work then it is a problem of your table view `delegate` or `datasource` methods called.Check these methods should definitely be called

1.`tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`
2.`tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`
3.`tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:`

You try to check if `titleforDeleteConfirmationbutton` is called at every time you click edit and check how many times it calls and also check if you are giving indent return value as yes in `shouldIndentwhileediting` method.

check your gesture recognizers.